# jquery datepicker - set minDate to first item in array which is set in beforeShow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code which sets an array of dates which I will be using to set selectable dates in a datepicker.

What I am struggling with is setting the minDate to the first date in this array.

Is this possible?

```
$('.propertyAvailabilityCal').datepicker({

        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            startDates = [];

            $(input).siblings("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
                  var startdateParts = $(this).val().split(', ');
                  startDates.push(startdateParts[0] + ", " + (parseInt(startdateParts[1], 10)-1) + ", " + parseInt(startdateParts[2], 10));
            });

            // SET minDate to the first date in the startDates array...

        }
    });
```

Here a fiddle to try to explain it better... It currently opens the datepicker on July (the current month because that's what I've set it to do), but I want it to realise that the first selectable date is 1st November and set that as the minDate.

http://jsfiddle.net/KEzXG/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Shall do, but can't right now...